# TableView - Header and section are not correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image]

I have some issues with header and section here. My view is below:

- Custom navigation with transparent.
- TableView frame = screen bounds, contentInset top = 64.
- TableView with header clear color.
- TableView has 1 section view (view has 3 tab).

  When I scroll tableview, section keep under navigation (perfect), but cells are scroll from section to top screen. I want cells only scroll in section, not to top and under navigation bar.

  Can I help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the table view `clipsToBounds` by default is false, which means it will be rendered outside the table view bounds.

A solution:

```
tableView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Not correct. Content is not outside because tableview is full screen. I think contentinset top = 64 and transparent navigation make this issue.

Comment: I see. Then can you make the table view not occupy the whole window, but just below the nav bar instead? With that you will have to remove the inset too. It should then work with the clipsToBounds.